# Javascript graph library for weather temperature

Tags: javascript, graphics, colors

i need to create a graph like this in javascript:

[image]

I've got the background image, the spots coords inside the image and the temperature values. I need to create and effect like the one in the image.

Does anyone know a javascript library that support this kind of graph?

Thanks

Comment: https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Gallery probably.

Comment: http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4241134